# Performance Enhancements in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, threadpool

Using the Threading model I have increased the amount of processing records from the DB in a service which has been implemented using Apache camel.

Now, I have to do the same but this time I'm getting the records from a queue. I'm a little vague but I'm thinking of using the Threading model so that I can process more than 1 record. My questions here are

1. Since earlier in case of processing records from DB I used to query around 10 records and have it processed by the number of threads available , in case of queue I'm not sure how this is going to work.
2. What are the other things I need to consider or know if the above mentioned is doable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveMQ component's option "concurrentConsumers" and give the value as to how many concurrent consumers you want on your camel route.

```
For example

from("jms:MyQueue?concurrentConsumers=5")
.to("bean:someBean");

or in XML DSL

<route>
<from uri="jms:MyQueue?concurrentConsumers=5"/>
<to uri="bean:someBean"/>
</route>
```

More details on activemq query options you can see [here](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/activemq-component.html).
See this also to unerstand more on [competing consumers](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/competing-consumers.html)

Comment: this is neat. So in general this is what i understand , when a message is received from the queue a thread is assigned to it for processing and after it is completed another thread is assigned for another process and so on. by increasing the concurrent consumers at once 5 messages will be received from the queue parallelly . Is there some way where we can monitor these thread at runtime ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.
You can use JMX to monitor the threads. You can also configure the threading model in camel which gives you more options to configure threadPoolProfile. (Don't forget to enable JMX if you are configuring threading model)
More on the threading model: https://camel.apache.org/manual/threading-model.html